# The Topics generated by the JTAC have no data

Tags: ros, joint-state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am working on creating a Moveit!-Gazebo Interface for my Robot and later also expanding it to create a Hardware Interface so that real Robot can act on the trajectory decided by MoveIt!

I have been successful in creating a Gazebo model (though it needs improvements) and also Interface it to RViz-MoveIt! and I see an actuation based on the  trajectory in MoveIt!

Since I am using the Joint Trajectory Action Controller I was doing a rostopic echo on the Action Topics thus created, and I was a bit surprised to find out that the Topics like

/follow_joint_trajectory/ goal
/follow_joint_trajectory/ feedback
/follow_joint_trajectory/ result
/follow_joint_trajectory/ cancel

did not have any data in them despite the Gazebo- MoveIt! Interface working well.

If these Topics have some issues then obviously i would be able to get the commands in to the Hardware Interface I would be writing.

Hence, I request some assistance in solving this problem. You may find my Repo
[over here](https://github.com/Sindhurakshak/SCARA.git)

I am cuurently using ROS Indigo. Is there someone who has faced this very issue in the Indigo ?

I would be very grateful if someone could point to the missing/ incorrect settings in my code.

Thanks a lot

Jalashwa

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269685/the-topics-generated-by-the-jtac-have-no-data/) by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only interface MoveIt! uses to communicate with the robot in gazebo is the ros-actions specified in [config/controllers.yaml](https://github.com/Sindhurakshak/SCARA/blob/master/sr_scara_hx_moveit_config/config/controllers.yaml).
So at least there *has* to be one message sent via the topic `/sr_scara_hx/sr_scara_hx_joint_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal` when you start to execute a trajectory.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0